# Network manager wireless connection duplicated

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have a wireless network named "sweet-home". Ubuntu sees it all right and for some time everything went fine, but at some point in the dropdown menu "sweet-home" turned into submenu with two items in it: "sweet-home" and "sweet-home 1". Is there a way I can clean this mess up and just have one "sweet-home"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In network indicator menu click on edit connections

[image]

Hare you can add/remove/edit your connections

[image]

This issue has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/713621).