# Wireless shows up and keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless, networking, password, netgear

I installed ubuntu for the first time (first time ever using linux) i used my friends wireless card to update but when i got home and put in my wireless card it asks me for a password i put in my password, it tries to connect for 20-40 seconds and then it asks again for password.. and every other device i have has had no problem connecting with the same password and network?

Comment: You need to provide more details, i.e. network card model, some relevant logs, configuration, etc.

Comment: Try to remove your wireless connection, Ubuntu will recreate it. You can do that in [Network Indicator](http://askubuntu.com/a/140068/37006).

Comment: This happens to me whenever I have a weak wireless connection, and is highly annoying.  If I leave my machine on overnight and return, I may have 50 popup windows asking me for the password.  Model is [zareason strata pro](http://zareason.com/shop/Strata-Pro-13.html)

Comment: Is your network encrypted? That will happen if you're on hardware that (or its driver) doesn't support your encryption protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change your wireless router's settings, examine the Channel Width and Mode.  I find that some network cards, particularly those with older chipsets, have trouble making and maintaining connections to routers with a Channel Width of 40MHz (or a router set to auto, which can adjust itself among multiple widths).  For me, the solution was to change Channel Width to 20MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Network Connections**

[image]

Got to the «Wireless» tab and choose your net. Enter the BSSID. It is something like «00:11:22:33:44:55»

[image]

Finally, check the «Wireless Security» tab. The most common security protocol is WEP (Hex or ASCII), but you can try other options.